# Creating a parser w/o JSON.parser

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I am trying to create a function that parses JSON text.

```js
function JSONParser(string) {
  //CODE HERE
  string = string.replace(/"/g, "");

  var obj = {};
  obj[0] = string;
  string = obj[0].replace(/'/g, "");

  return string;
}
```

I only did the funky thing with the object because .replace didn't seem to work directly on the string the second time.

When I run this code through a checker. I get...

```js
JSONParser(JSON.stringify(true));
"true"
```

I am aiming to return the boolean true and not a string.

Does anyone know why I still get a return with double quotes? Is there more to changing a string object than removing the quotes? Or, am I simply trying to remove them incorrectly?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. TIA

-Lea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's still a string, so the console displays it with quotes *(as decoration)*.

Remember, when you do `var foo = "true"`, the quotes aren't actually part of the string, so there's no need to remove them. Your console just shows them as a way to indicate the type of data it's showing. They're not actually there.

If you want a boolean, you can do something like this:

```js
function JSONParser(string) {
  return string === "true" ? true :
         string === "false" ? false : string;
}

console.log(JSONParser(JSON.stringify(true)));
```

If the string is neither `"true"` nor `"false"`, it just returns the original string.

---

If you prefer `if` statements, then:

```js
function JSONParser(string) {
  if (string === "true") {
    return true;
  } else if (string === "false") {
    return false;
  } else {
    return string;
  }
}

console.log(JSONParser(JSON.stringify(true)));
```

Or a `switch` statement would be useful too.